# C# Search for a word occurances within a string

Tags: c#

How can I search for a word within a string ?
I have one text box which the user insert a string and another on with with text just some random text. 
Are there any alterative ways of doing this besides using `regex` and `IndexOf`? Like using a `for loop` and checking the length and character in the word.

This is what I tried so far

```
        int i = 0; 
        int count = 0;

        input2.Trim(); 

        while ((i = input2.IndexOf(input1, i)) != -1) 
        {
            i = i + input1.Length;
            count++; 
        }

        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString() + " Matches Found");
```

Comment: You are using `IndexOf` - that's not using regex.

Comment: @ Oded Im aware of that ^^ i was just wondering if there are any other ways of doing this ?

Comment: @Oded you are right. It does not... deleting my comments... I had a brain freeze or something like that I guess.

Comment: Why are you looking for other ways? What's the issue with what you have now?

Comment: Well there's no issues with my code I was just wondering if ,for example you can use something like  a for loop like. for( int i = 0; i < input1.lenght; i++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to get the Count of search string in the text. You can try the following.

```
string searchString = "TEST";
string completeText = "Some sentence TEST with other words incluing TEST";
int count = completeText.Split(new string[]{"TEST"},StringSplitOptions.None)
                        .Count() - 1;
MessageBox.Show(count.ToString() + " Matches Found");
```

Comment: Hah, hadn't thought of this. There's _always_ another way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to match the number of occurances,

```
string test = "THE DOG WENT TO TOWN DOG";
int j = Regex.Matches(test, "DOG").Cast<Match>().Count();
```

Comment: The code clearly intends to _count_ the number of occurrences. This doesn't help.

Comment: -1 for the edit. OP is asking for _alternatives_ to both `IndexOf` **and** `Regex`.